# Webpack cannot find module after updating package

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, node-modules, npm-install

All I did was change one package version manually in my `package.json` file and then `npm install` and now when I run the webpack-dev-server I get an error saying "uncaught Error: Cannot find module relative path at webpackMissingModule"

What I've tried:

- `rm -rf node_modules` then `npm install`
- `npm clear cache --force`
- revert changes going back to the original package version
- del `package.lock.json` then `npm install --package-lock-only`

None of these solutions worked and the package was working before I changed the version number.

Here is the full error thrown

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '../../../src/Utils/BaseStyles'
    at webpackMissingModule (Card.js:43)
    at Object../node_modules/X (Card.js:43)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object../node_modules/X (index.js:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object../node_modules/X (index.js:26)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:789)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
``
```

Comment: what version you are getting error

Comment: @MeghshyamSonar changed version from ^2.3.57 to 2.3.64

Comment: Please upgrading it to ^2.25.2

Comment: dependencies: {
    ...
    "moment": "^2.25.2",
    ...
}

Comment: @MeghshyamSonar Thanks, but that didn't seem to fix the issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps

1. Remove `package.json.lock` file from folder where your angular project
   is
2. Install angular cli lib by running `npm install -g @angular/cli`
3. Remove node_modules folder and install npm packages by running `npm install`
4. Rebuild `node-sass` binary by running `npm rebuild node-sass`
5. Run project with command `ng serve -o`